# Can I recursively call an async function without overflowing the stack?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Since the return site of the async function isn't the caller, I assume this works, but thought I'd verify that this was safe just in case. If it's not, why would this overflow the stack?

```
static async Task CheckAsync(TimeSpan recursiveTimer)
{
    // do some work

    await Task.Delay(recursiveTimer);
    CheckAsync(recursiveTimer);
}
```

Edit:
I decided to just try it out - it looks like it does not overflow the stack (it's running on my machine now - it's currently on call 210,000). My assumed reason is that because the return site of the CheckAsync function is not actually CheckAsync, but instead somewhere in the async plumbing. So when CheckAsync calls CheckAsync, it's not actually adding to the call stack via the normal function call mechanism, but instead putting the function as an object on some async "to be executed" queue, which is run via some other thread managing async functions.

To anyone that knows this mechanism well: does this sound about right?

Comment: Why don't you try it while you're at it? If it overflows the stack, it'll throw in a few seconds.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `await CheckAsync(recursiveTimer)`?

Comment: @jon-skeet Specifically not `await`! The idea is that if I *don't* await `CheckAsync`, I assume the return location is not the call site, but something in the plumbing of async/await

Comment: Just because this site is named StackOverflow doesn't mean you should ask about stack overflow...I jest I jest...I'm wondering if `.ContinueWith(x=>CheckAsync)` after a TaskDelay is equivalent to your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it's working for you is not because of the way `CheckAsync` is called, but because you're awaiting the result of `Task.Delay`. That will always return a "not completed yet" task, so awaiting it will schedule a continuation. That continuation will be fired on an effectively empty stack, so it doesn't matter that you then make the recursive call.

Now, I think you still effectively have a memory leak, because IIRC the framework will be keeping track of a "logical stack" which will get bigger and bigger... but that will be stored on the heap and expand until you run out of memory.

If you want to see the stack blow up, all you need to do is change the code to:

```
static async Task CheckAsync(TimeSpan recursiveTimer)
{
    // Whatever
    await Task.FromResult(5);
    CheckAsync(recursiveTimer);
}
```

At that point, assuming the code in "whatever" doesn't await anything, you'll have entirely synchronous code, just using `Task` for keeping track of completion and exceptions.

I certainly wouldn't recommend this as a pattern for repeatedly doing work (partly due to the memory leak I mentioned), but I hope that explains why you're not getting a stack overflow.

Comment: Indeed it does blow up! Even if there wasn't a memory concern related to the 'logical stack', I am inclined not to do this because the next dev that looks at it likely won't think "hey, that `Task.Delay` can be something else". Do you happen to know a good link describing how stacks/continuations work? I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around it.

Comment: @Rollie: You could start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh191443.aspx - alternatively, I have a Pluralsight course on it, and chapter 15 of the 3rd edition of C# in Depth covers it fairly extensively :)

Comment: I tried running the following code and haven't found the process size go up as I expected. I'm close to 300,000 calls and my app size is less than 3 MB and not increasing linearly. Granted, I'm using ContinueWith instead of await.
 `private static void callme()
  {  
   if(++counter%1000==0)
    Console.WriteLine(counter);
   if (counter == long.MaxValue) return;
   Task.Delay(1).ContinueWith(x => callme());
  }`

Comment: @arviman: I suspect that old tasks are getting garbage collected as the new tasks are being created. Just a guess though.

Comment: @JonSkeet: That seems to be the only explanation. I ended up running it till a million calls and it worked fine with no memory bloat. Guess the tasks are being recycled in the thread pool.

Answer (score 1):

Reason why it overflows is because overflows stack.

```
10 static async Task CheckAsync(TimeSpan recursiveTimer)
20 {
30    // do some work
40    await Task.Delay(recursiveTimer);
50    CheckAsync(recursiveTimer);
60 }
```

Code execution would go

```
10 20 30 40 50 60                         //CheckAsync(recursiveTimer)
            10 20 30 40 50 60             //CheckAsync(CheckAsync(recursiveTimer))
                        10 20 30 40 50 60 //CheckAsync(CheckAsync(CheckAsync(recursiveTimer))
```

Contents of that method should be something like:

```
while(doCheck){
  await Task.Delay(recursiveTimer);
  CheckAsync(recursiveTimer);
}
```

Assuming you want to wait after every async call and do this while **doCheck** is true. I assume that you change **doCheck** value in another thread.

Take a look at : [Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the article reference! It doesn't seem to mention anything about recursion specifically. I decided to just try it out - it looks like it does *not* overflow the stack. My assumed reason is that because the return site of the CheckAsync function is not actually CheckAsync, but instead somewhere in the async plumbing. So when CheckAsync calls CheckAsync, it's not actually adding to the call stack via the normal function call mechanism, but instead putting the function as an object on some async "to be executed" queue, which is run via some other thread managing async functions.

Comment: Too many times I've contemplated recursion when the simpler loop would suffice. Your example would benefit with the addition of some sort of _Cancellation_. Nonetheless +1.